# multipart file upload in angular4

Tags: angular, multipartform-data, angular-forms

How can I convert this method into multipart form so I can upload image and text together. Can someone tell me what changes need to be done.

here is my code-

```
    save(event: any, type, image_type) {
    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
        const file: File = fileList[0]
        this.files = file;
        this._data.data.is_image_send = true;
    }


    this._data.data.files = this.files;
    console.log(this._data.data)
    this.productdetails = this._data.data;


    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
        this.url2 = event.target.result;
        this.upload = true;

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);


}
```

Comment: where is the `image` and `text` you mean the image file name and the image?

Comment: No. I have to send image in an object along with some other variables like product name, user name etc

Comment: create a complex object and create a web service to accept that complex object and post it to service

Comment: I have a data service where I am storing all the values.

Comment: does that service accepts `file`?

Comment: yes. It does. do you want to see the service?

Comment: I want to see the object that is accepted in the backend?

Comment: [ { fieldname: 'photo',
    originalname: 'IMG-20180319-WA0009.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: '/home/saransh/Desktop/flamingo_backup/,
    filename: '419cea9fda09f3c7b1dd1',
    path: '/home/saransh/Desktop/flamingo_backup/flamingo/,
    size: 126010 } ]

Comment: this is the request..req.decoded._id;
req.body.name;
req.body.productId;
req.body.userProductId || null;
req.body.description || "";
req.body.securityDeposit || 0;
req.body.chargePerDay;
req.body.weeklyPrice;
req.body.monthlyPrice;
req.body.disabledDates || [];
req.body.is_approved;
req.body.is_image_send;
req.files;